# Python resolve shell backquoted string

Tags: python, shell

how can I resolve a (shell) back-quoted string in python?

Say, I have the string `` "`cat /etc/hosts | grep hostname`" ``, and I want to get the shell interpretation of it, e.g: "0.0.0.0 hostname\n".  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`shlex.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('cat /etc/hosts | grep hostname')
['cat', '/etc/hosts', '|', 'grep', 'hostname']
```

If, however, you are looking for the *output* of the command in backticks, you'd need to use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output('cat /etc/hosts | grep dahn', shell=True)
'127.0.0.1\tdahnlocal.internal.int\n'
```

Note that I set `shell` to `True` to have the shell interpret it for me.

Comment: Someone needs to slip you some prozac (I won't bother posting then!) +1

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough, I don't want to parse it, I want to get the results, as if I'd typed the string in a shell.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for.